# How to split a sentence and save it in different arrays?

Tags: android

I have an rss feed in which i need to fetch description data and save it in an array. But in my rss feed i have image and description. how can i split them and save in seperate arrays. one in image array and description ion description array.

Below is the description tag coming from rss feed :

`<img src='http://static.ibnlive.in.com/ibnlive/pix/sitepix/04_2010/3g-mobile_0904_630_90x62.jpg'>`

The Telecom Disputethe role was tailor made for her, the 'Billa' and 'Yei' girl says she is even ready to bring down her remuneration, if she is offered with the role.

Can any one of you help me?

Comment: What you have tried? Post your code....

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression in java to split the string into two parts.

Use the String function `split` with the required [regular expression](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/) as parameter or write your own`pattern matching algorithm` to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the [AndroidRssReader](https://github.com/robhinds/AndroidRssReader) project to parse the necessary info from RSS feeds

Answer (score 0):

```
      String x="Ask on stackoverflow";
    String[] tokens=x.split(" ");
    for(String t:tokens){
        System.err.println(t);
    }
```

Output

```
           Ask
           on
           stackoverflow
```